# Confusing behavior with std::is_constructible and if constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

Probably easiest to explain if I show an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Unconstructible
{
public:
    Unconstructible() = delete;
};


int main()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<Unconstructible>)
    {
        std::cout << "Unconstructible is constructible. What?\n";
        // Unconstructible foo;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unconstructible is not constructible.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs "Unconstructible is not constructible" as expected. If, however, I uncomment the line `Unconstructible foo;`, I get a compilation error:

```
1>F:\Programming\C++\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork.cpp(48): error C2280: 'Unconstructible::Unconstructible(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>F:\Programming\C++\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork.cpp(39): message : see declaration of 'Unconstructible::Unconstructible'
1>F:\Programming\C++\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork\CppScratchwork.cpp(39,5): message : 'Unconstructible::Unconstructible(void)': function was explicitly deleted
1>Done building project "CppScratchwork.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

That's in MSVC using /std:c++17. The same behavior shows up on GCC with -std=c++17 but with differently-worded error messages involving attempting to reference a deleted function.

Why is it even attempting to compile the first part of the `if constexpr` branch? As far as I can tell, it is correctly able to tell that `std::is_constructible_v<Unconstructible>` is `false`.

Comment: To summarize the duplicate (there may be a better one): *This means every branch in an if constexpr block must be valid C++, even if it's never going to be used.*

Comment: Too bad the duplicate doesn't define "valid C++" very well. Apparently more is needed than merely to be parseable.

Comment: Ah. I think the misunderstanding I had was for the fact that the un-taken branch of `if constexpr` doesn't attempt to instantiate templates that would only be instantiated there and over-generalized that to "code in un-taken branches of `if constexpr` doesn't really have to compile".

Comment: Added a second duplicate target that emphasizes the difference when using templates; in that case, you *can* have 'badly-formed' code (sort of).

Comment: That explains why, for instance, I can happily put `auto p_unconstructible = std::make_unique<Unconstructible>();` in the upper branch, because that's only invalid if it actually attempts to instantiate the template function.